# How to use a input as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have now coded:

```
a = [{1,2,3}, {3,4}, {2,8}]
```

But is it also possible to get this list from a users input?

I tried this:

```
> a = (input("Enter your list like this and click enter: [{1,2,3},
> {3,4}] "))
```

But apparently the input "a" is a string and not a list because a few rules further I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'set' and 'str'
```

How can I let the user fill in something like the list above, and convert it to a list/set?

I hope someone understands what I mean, its pretty hard to explain this :P
Also, im not allowed to import anything.

Comment: you could maybe do this by asking for each element

Comment: If you need to do this without importing, you will need to build a parser to read through the input one character at a time and build the sets.

Comment: Your're using a dictionary for the lists inside of lists, which probably isn't what you want. (Google python dictionaries) What you want would be like:
[[1,2,3], [3,4], [2,8]]

Comment: @Exp it is a **list of sets**. You can check it using type()

Comment: @Errol Oops! My bad :/

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
a = literal_eval(input("Enter your list like this and click enter: [{1,2,3}, {3,4}] "))
# input [{1,2,3}, {3,4}]
```

output:

```
[{1,2,3}, {3,4}]
```

`ast` is a built-in module, not a third party

Answer (score 0):

Here is a restricted parser assuming a user input (str) of a list of sets of integers.

This uses common string methods.  It's not what you actually want to implement in real code, but satisfies the OP's requirements.

**Code**

```
def _to_ints(s):
    """Convert strings to int."""
    return map(int, s.split(","))


def _convert_container(s):
    """Convert strings to sets."""
    b = s[:]
    b = b.strip("{}[]()")
    b = _to_ints(b)
    res = set(b)
    return res


def parse(s: str) -> list:
    """Convert the string to objects.

    Assumes stringed list of sets.

    """
    s = s.strip("[]")
    s = s.replace(" ", "")
    lst = s.split("},")
    res = list(map(_convert_container, lst))
    return res
```

**Tests**

```
assert [{1, 2, 3}] == parse("[{1,2,3}]")
assert [{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6}] == parse("[{1,2,3}, {5,6}]")
assert [{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6}] == parse("[{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6}]")
```

Answer (score -1):

@ironkey made a good suggestion, to just ask each element in succession.

If you really want to parse Python syntax instead, eval() exists to do that. Note however that it's usually never a good idea to use for anything real. Makes your code fragile, and is a security problem if you get the input from some actual users that could run malicious code on your system. That said, it works like this - is fine to play with it for learning purposes:

```py
> inputstr = "[{1,2,3}, {3,4}, {2,8}]" #you can get this with input() which gives a string
> inputdata = eval(inputstr)
> inputdata
[{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4}, {8, 2}]
```